# Android Studio can't record screen at 1080p

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, recording, video-recording

I am trying to record my Nexus 7 2013 (1080p) with Android Studio 1.5.1 (stable).

In the settings, I put :

Bitrate : 10Mbps
WxH : 1200 1900

I cannot use 1080 * 1900 because 1080 is not a multiple of 16.

As soon as I click on start with the aforementioned settings, the record stops and produces a file with a previous recording performed with default settings (720p, 4Mbps).

Why ?

I once successfully made a 1080p video with the same device but I cannot remember how I did it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb` directly to record 1080p video

```
abd shell
screenrecord --size 1080x1920 /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

If the device you are recording on is a 1080p device, then adb by default records in 1080p.

Detaild tutorial : http://www.androidauthority.com/android-customization-screen-recording-adb-599331/